# Akka scheduler : strange behavior in production (messages not firing)

Tags: multithreading, scala, jdbc, akka, akka-cluster

I'm developing an scala + akka app as part as a bigger application. The purpose of the app is to call external services and SQL databases (using JDBC), do some processing, and return a parsed result, on a recurrent basis. The app uses akka cluster so that it can scale horizontally.

**How it should work**

I'm creating a **singleton actor* on the cluster who's responsible for sending instructions to a pool of *instruction handlers* actors. I'm receiving events from a Redis pub/sub channel that state which *datasources* should be refreshed and how often. This *SourceScheduler* actor stores in an internal Array the instruction along with the interval.

Then I'm using akka Scheduler to execute a *tick* function every second. This function filters the array to determine which instructions need to be executed, and sends messages to the instructions handlers pool. The routees in the pool execute the instructions and emit the results through Redis Pub/Sub

**The issue**

On my machine (Ryzen 7 + 16GB RAM + ArchLinux) everything runs fine and we're processing easily 2500 database calls/second. But once in production, I cannot get it to process more than ~400 requests/s.

The SourceScheduler doesn't *tick* every second, and messages get stuck in the mailbox. Also, the app uses more CPU resources, and way more RAM (1.3GB in production vs ~350MB on my machine)

The production app runs in a JRE-8 alpine-based Docker container on Rancher, on a MS Azure server.

I understand that singleton actors on clusters *can* be a bottleneck, but since it only forwards messages to other actors I don't see how it could block.

**What I've tried**

- I use Tomcat JDBC as connection pool manager for SQL queries. I'm sure I don't leak any a connection for I log every connection that is borrowed from the pool and every connection that returns to it
- Blocking operations like JDBC queries are all executed on a separate dispatcher, a fixed thread pool executer with 500 threads, so all other actors should run properly
- I've also given the SourceScheduler actor a dedicated pinned dispatcher so it should run on it's own thread
- I've tried running the app in cluster with 3 nodes, with no performance improvement. Since the SourceScheduler is a singleton, running multiple nodes does not resolve the issue
- I've tried the app on my coworker's machine. Works like a charm. I'm only experiencing issues with the production server
- I've tried upgrading the production server to the most powerful available on Azure (16 cores, 2.3ghz) with no noticeable change

**As anyone ever experienced such differences between their local machine and the production server ?**

---

**EDIT** SourceScheduler.scala

```
class SourceScheduler extends Actor with ActorLogging with Timers {
  case object Tick
  case object SchedulerReport
  import context.dispatcher

  val instructionHandlerPool = context.actorOf(
    ClusterRouterGroup(
      RoundRobinGroup(Nil),
      ClusterRouterGroupSettings(
        totalInstances = 10,
        routeesPaths = List("/user/instructionHandler"),
        allowLocalRoutees = true
      )
    ).props(),
    name = "instructionHandlerRouter")

  var ticks: Int = 0
  var refreshedSources: Int = 0
  val maxTicks: Int = Int.MaxValue - 1

  var scheduledSources = Array[(String, Int, String)]()

  override def preStart(): Unit = {
    log.info("Starting Scheduler")
  }

  def refreshSource(hash: String) = {
    instructionHandlerPool ! Instruction(hash)
    refreshedSources += 1
  }

  // Get sources that neeed to be refreshed
  def getEligibleSources(sources: Seq[(String, Int, String)], tick: Int) = {
    sources.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.toList.minBy(_._2)).values.filter(tick * 1000 % _._2 == 0).map(_._1)
  }

  def tick(): Unit = {
    ticks += 1
    log.debug("Scheduler TICK {}", ticks)
    val eligibleSources = getEligibleSources(scheduledSources, ticks)
    val chunks = eligibleSources.grouped(ConnectionPoolManager.connectionPoolSize).zipWithIndex.toList
    log.debug("Scheduling {} sources in {} chunks", eligibleSources.size, chunks.size)
    chunks.foreach({
      case(sources, index) =>
        after((index * 25 + 5) milliseconds, context.system.scheduler)(Future.successful {
          sources.foreach(refreshSource)
        })
    })
    if(ticks >= maxTicks) ticks = 0
  }
  timers.startPeriodicTimer("schedulerTickTimer", Tick, 990 milliseconds)
  timers.startPeriodicTimer("schedulerReportTimer", SchedulerReport, 10 seconds)

  def receive: Receive = {
    case AttachSource(hash, interval, socketId) =>
      scheduledSources.synchronized {
        scheduledSources = scheduledSources :+ ((hash, interval, socketId))
      }
    case DetachSource(socketId) =>
      scheduledSources.synchronized {
        scheduledSources = scheduledSources.filterNot(_._3 == socketId)
      }
    case SchedulerReport =>
      log.info("{} sources were scheduled since last report", refreshedSources)
      refreshedSources = 0
    case Tick => tick()
    case _ =>
  }
}
```

Each source has is determined by a hash containing all required data for the execution (like the host of the database for example), the refresh interval, and the unique id of the client that asked for it so we can stop refreshing when the client disconnects.
Each second, we check if the source needs to be refreshed by applying a modulo with the current value  of the *ticks* counter.
We refresh sources in smaller chunks to avoid connection pool starvation
The problem is that under a small load (~300 rq/s) the tick function is no longer executed every second

Comment: is very hard to say really, when you run it locally do you also run it in a docker instance? how much have you gone in replicating the environment where the application runs?

Comment: I've tried to run it in a docker instance too. It works.
I've running it on a slower computer that matches the server's capabilities better, and while I do get worse performance, it's not even close to the catastrophic performance and freezes I experience on the production server.
I could try to run it on a virtual machine running docker but I was hoping I could avoid doing this ...

Comment: @GuillaumeB. Can you show us your `SourceScheduler` Actor?

Comment: @rgcase sure! I made an edit

Comment: I can't do that because the after pattern requires a future as second argument if I'm correct.
Buy anyway, it turns out the issue was with Rancher so I'm closing the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the issue was with Rancher.
We did several tests and the app was running fine on the machine directly, and on docker, but not when using Rancher as the orchestrator. I'm not sure why but since it's not related to Akka I'm closing the issue. 
Thanks everyone for your help.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe the bottleneck is on the network latency? In your machine all components are running side by side and communication should have no latency but in the cluster, if you are making a high number of database calls from one machine to another the network latency may be noticeable.

Comment: Yeah, I thought that too, but unfortunately no. In either case, I'm running queries against a remote database. I log the average time the queries take and they don't exceed ~25ms. I'm using a connection pool of 128 connections at most so I should be able to run 5000 rq/s easily.
The issue doesn't seem to be that my processing actors cannot handle the queries but rather that the scheduler doesn't send enough messages to them (i.e it blocks completely at some point)